# How do I use Python regex replace only if all lines match?

Tags: python, regex

Python regex for multiline search/replace. 
Change:

```
x a
x b
```

Into:

```
y a
y b
```

But only if there are 2+ lines starting with x

Comment: `x -> y` or `x a -> y a, x b -> y b` ?

Comment: The a and b were meant to be just the rest of the line. To be kept but not important. x->y for all lines iff all lines start with x. Regex preferred but anything acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Python's `groupby` function for this as follows:

```
from itertools import groupby

text = """x a
x b
x c
a b
x d
a b
x 123
x 234
x 345
a b
x a
x b"""

for k, g in groupby(text.split('\n'), lambda x: x.startswith('x')):
    lines = list(g)
    if k and len(lines) >= 2:
        lines = ['y' + line[1:] for line in lines]
    print '\n'.join(lines)
```

This would display the following:

```
y a
y b
y c
a b
x d
a b
y 123
y 234
y 345
a b
y a
y b
```

Tested using Python 2.7.9

Answer (score 0):

Use `re.findall` and `re.sub`:

```js
def replace(text):
    regex = re.compile(r'(?m)^x')
    if len(regex.findall(text)) > 1:
        return regex.sub('y', text)
    return text

text = '''foobar
x a
c
xa b
e
xx c
a b
x d
a b
x 123
e
x 234
x 345
ax b
x a
x b
x a
e
'''
```

```
print replace(text)
```

output:

```
foobar
y a
c
ya b
e
yx c
a b
y d
a b
y 123
e
y 234
y 345
ax b
y a
y b
y a
e
```

and

```
>>> print replace('x')
x
>>> print replace('xa')
xa
>>> print replace('xaxcxc')
xaxcxc
>>> print replace('xa\nxcxc')
ya
ycxc
>>> print replace('axa\nxc\nxc')
axa
yc
yc
>>> print replace('xa\nxc\nxc')
ya
yc
yc
```